# How to target a container on the top of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div class="a"></div> //notice the the container is closed
<div class="b"></div>
```

I know that you can target the .b class by using class **".a + div"** but how can I do that vise versa?

I want to hide the .a class upon clicking .b class.

Answer (score 2):

Try below jQuery code

```
$('.b').click(function(){
 $(this).prev('div').hide();
});
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't that prev and next will do the thing. I thought I need some css targeting for that. It works like a charm @PPL. Thank you :)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps to you. it may be helpful to others

Answer (score 1):

Hide div with [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method. So, you can hide div on `.b` 's click event.

```js
$('.b').on('click',function(){
 $(this).prev('.a').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">a</div> //notice the the container is closed
<div class="b">div b</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work and also straight forward approach

```
 $(function(){
      $('.b').click(function(){
        $('.a').hide();
      });
   });
```